Deno: programatically get the local file path of cached npm module
For native deno modules, there is this question and answer. However, this doesn't seem to work for modules that Deno downloaded from npm. (And the other alternative, using the deno vendor, is apparently deprecated).
Thus my question: If I have e.g. npm:ts-blank-space (which works to import and run in my deno project), how do I get the string ~/Library/Caches/deno/npm/registry.npmjs.org/ts-blank-space/0.4.1/out/index.js programatically?
Or alternatively getting that file's contents would actually be enough for my use-case as well. But I haven't found a way to do that either (e.g. dynamic imports don't seem to expose the module contents under toString() or similar).
